# Deploying different versions of the same application with Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I am new Kubernetes and I have a use case where I am trying to deploy multiple versions of the application on to a same cluster.
My case: A Java application which is hosted in a cluster under a particular namespace and is getting data from an onprem data source.
Requirement: Need another version of the same app which will read/get data from a different onprem data source.

My doubt here is that will it be possible for me to upload the second version of the application under the same namespace? Should I be using a different namespace? or should I rather look for a different cluster?

Deployment.yml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: test-helloworld-gkp
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: test-helloworld-gkp
  replicas: 2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: test-helloworld-gkp
    spec:
      securityContext:
        runAsUser: 999
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: image-pulling-secret
      containers:
        - name: test-helloworld-gkp
          image: app-image
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          resources:
            requests:
              memory: 5Gi
              cpu: 625mm
            limits:
              memory: 5Gi
              cpu: 625mm
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
          envFrom:
            - configMapRef:
                name: app-runtime-test-helloworld-gkp
          env:
            # JVM Memory Settings for 1Gi total container memory. Bump the -Xmx setting to match any increase to container memory.
            - name: JAVA_OPTS
              value: -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=10M -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=105M -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240M -Xss1M -Xmx420M
            - name: SERVER_FORWARD_HEADERS_STRATEGY
              value: NATIVE
            - name: SERVER_TOMCAT_REMOTEIP_INTERNAL_PROXIES
              value: .*
            # Kubernetes related info for Actuator
            - name: INFO_KUBE_ENV
              value: ${environment}
            - name: INFO_KUBE_CLUSTER
              value: ${cluster}
            - name: INFO_KUBE_IMAGE
              value: ${containerImageUri}
            - name: INFO_KUBE_NAMESPACE
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  fieldPath: metadata.namespace
            - name: INFO_KUBE_POD_NAME
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  fieldPath: metadata.name
            - name: INFO_KUBE_POD_IP
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  fieldPath: status.podIP
            - name: INFO_KUBE_NODE_NAME
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  fieldPath: spec.nodeName
          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /actuator/keepalive
              port: 8080
              httpHeaders:
                - name: x-forwarded-proto
                  value: https
            timeoutSeconds: 5
            initialDelaySeconds: 600
            periodSeconds: 10
          livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /actuator/keepalive
              port: 8080
              httpHeaders:
                - name: x-forwarded-proto
                  value: https
            timeoutSeconds: 5
            initialDelaySeconds: 600
            periodSeconds: 10
---
apiVersion: apps/v2
kind: Deployment
  metadata:
    name: test-helloworld-gkp-v1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: test-helloworld-gkp-v1
  replicas: 2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: test-helloworld-gkp-v1
    spec:
      securityContext:
        runAsUser: 999
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: image-pulling-secret
      containers:
        - name: test-helloworld-gkp-v1
          image: app-image-2
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          resources:
            requests:
              memory: 5Gi
              cpu: 625m
            limits:
              memory: 5Gi
              cpu: 625m
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8081
          envFrom:
            - configMapRef:
                name: app-runtime-test-helloworld-gkp
          env:
            # JVM Memory Settings for 1Gi total container memory. Bump the -Xmx setting to match any increase to container memory.
            - name: JAVA_OPTS
              value: -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=10M -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=105M -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240M -Xss1M -Xmx420M
            - name: SERVER_FORWARD_HEADERS_STRATEGY
              value: NATIVE
            - name: SERVER_TOMCAT_REMOTEIP_INTERNAL_PROXIES
              value: .*
            # Kubernetes related info for Actuator
            - name: INFO_KUBE_ENV
              value: ${environment}
            - name: INFO_KUBE_CLUSTER
              value: ${cluster}
            - name: INFO_KUBE_IMAGE
              value: ${containerImageUri}
            - name: INFO_KUBE_NAMESPACE
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  fieldPath: metadata.namespace
            - name: INFO_KUBE_POD_NAME
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  fieldPath: metadata.name
            - name: INFO_KUBE_POD_IP
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  fieldPath: status.podIP
            - name: INFO_KUBE_NODE_NAME
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  fieldPath: spec.nodeName
          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /actuator/keepalive
              port: 8081
              httpHeaders:
                - name: x-forwarded-proto
                  value: https
            timeoutSeconds: 5
            initialDelaySeconds: 600
            periodSeconds: 10
          livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /actuator/keepalive
              port: 8081
              httpHeaders:
                - name: x-forwarded-proto
                  value: https
            timeoutSeconds: 5
            initialDelaySeconds: 600
            periodSeconds: 10
```

Error when executing the kubectl apply

```
[unable to recognize "kube\\kustomize\\overlays\\local": no matches for kind "Service" in version "v1beta1", unable to recognize "kube\\kustomize\\overlays\\local": no matches for kind "Deployment" in version "apps/v1beta1"]
Error from server (BadRequest): error when creating "kube\\kustomize\\overlays\\local": Deployment in version "v1" cannot be handled as a Deployment: unable to parse quantity's suffix
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My doubt here is that will it be possible for me to upload the second version of the application under the same namespace? Should I be using a different namespace? or should I rather look for a different cluster?

You can deploy the two different versions, at the same time, if you use **two different** `Deployment` resources. If you use a `Service`, you probably want two different `Service` resources as well - e.g. with different names, like `my-service-v1` and `my-service-v2`.

Comment: I have them both Deployment.yml and Service.yml, which one takes priority?

Comment: You, typically use both.

Comment: So specify the service's name in the Service,yml and the deploymenty configuraions for each of the service in the Deployment.yml right?

Comment: Do you have any reference ?

Comment: @Ananya you must describe what problems you encounter. What is your problem? What have you tried? What error did you get?

Comment: I have edited the question with a version of deployment yml that I am using to deploy two images of the same app, I am not able to compile it since it says most of the keys are duplicated

Comment: @Ananya as I wrote in my answer, you need **two** Deployment, one for each version - and they cannot have the same name.

Comment: My bad I have modified the versions and the metadata names are different now, but when I do a apply am I getting the an error which I have added to the question as well

Comment: Thank you, @Jonas I was able to upload two different versions of the app as two different images by using two deployments and service level ymls